# jquery getting back the image after the drop

Tags: jquery

After the user puts an image url in the field the value of the img tag is changed and the user can drag and drop the image to the #centerhead part of the box.  Now the issue I am having is after the img is dropped it disappears and I want have the img tag back at it's original location ready to take another image url.

```
function addToPart() {
    var URLText = document.getElementById("txtURLText");
    var bpart = document.getElementById("BodySelect");
    if (URLText.value != "") {
        var UT = URLText.value;

        var bpartValue; 
        switch (bpart.value) {
            case "1":
                bpartValue = "#centerhead";
                break;
            case "2":
                bpartValue = "#centerbody";
                break;
            case "3":
                bpartValue = "#RightArm";
                break;
            case "4":
                bpartValue = "#leftArm";
                break;
            case "5":
                bpartValue = "#legs";
                break;
            case "6":
                bpartValue = "#feet";
                break;         
        }
       //the function that appends the values to the table
        addToArea(bpartValue,UT);
    }

};
//this adds the picture to the table when the part had been choosen
function addToArea(bvalue,UT) {
$(bvalue).find('tbody')
.append($('<tr>')
    .append($('<td>')
        .append($('<img>')
            .attr('src', UT)
                .attr('id',UT)

        )
    )
);



};



 //this takes the picture URL and put the pic in the test image
function showPic() {
    var URLText = document.getElementById("txtURLText").value;
     document.getElementById("testImage").src=URLText;
  //this makes test image draggable
     $(function () {
         $("#testImage").draggable();
     });

     //TODO once the image is dropped it simply disapears.  Need to clone it back to it's orignal spot.
     $(function () {
         $("#centerhead").droppable({
             drop: function (event, ui) {
                 $("#centerhead").append(ui.draggable);
                 addToArea("#centerhead", URLText);
                 // $("#testImage").clone().appendTo('#dragging');
                 $("#dragging").append($('<img>')
            .attr('src', '')
                .attr('id', 'testImage')
                )
                 $("#txtURLText").attr('value', ''); 
             }
         });

     });


};




 <div id="test1D">
    <table id="wholeBody">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr><td></td><td><table id="centerhead"><thead><tr><th>Head</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table></td><td></td></tr>

    <tr><td><table id="RightArm"><thead><tr><th>Right Arm</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table></td><td><table id="centerbody"><thead><tr><th>Body</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table></td><td><table id="leftArm"><thead><tr><th>LeftArm</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table></td></tr>

     <tr><td></td><td><table id="legs"><thead><tr><th>Legs</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table></td><td></td></tr>

     <tr><td></td><td><table id="feet"><thead><tr><th>Feet</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table></td><td></td></tr>

    </tbody>

    </table>
   <div id="dragging">
    <img alt="Place image here" src=""  id="testImage"/>
    </div>
  <input id="txtURLText" type="text" onchange="showPic()" />
   <select id="BodySelect" onchange="addToPart()">
        <option></option>
       <option  value="1">head</option>
            <option value="2">body</option>
            <option value="3">RightArm</option>
            <option value="4">LeftArm</option>
            <option value="5">legs</option>
            <option value="6">feet</option>
        </select>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using droppable ui from jQuery for dragging the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's suppose you are using jQuery draggable and droppable functions.

First you need to declare a holder for the image ( the one that change when the user enter the image url from the input box ) and do the following:

```
   var  $holder_image = $( "div#image_draggable" ),

$holder_image.draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move"
});
```

As you can see, once declared the image_draggable container it's important to declare the helper **clone** which means that this container can be dragged&dropped many times.

After you must declare the receptor's (the areas where the image can be dropped) with the following:

```
$areas_to_drop = $( ".image_holders" ); // this selector select all possible containers where the image can be dropped
$areas_to_drop.droppable({
        accept: "#image_draggable",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
           // Here you add the necessary functionality once the image is dropped. It's an event. Not required in case there's nothing to do.
        }
});
```

So, basically, with this you can drag&drop one image the times you want keeping the original image.

If the user change the image url, the content from the #image_draggable holder will change and ready to be dragged&dropped.

Hope this help.